# php function fgets() unexpectet result

Tags: php

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

    define("KPA_PEOPLE","/devel/pic/snk_db2/KPA-migration/Keywords/gettingTheKeywordsAndFiles/KPA_People.txt");
    $hndl_kpa_people=fopen(KPA_PEOPLE,"r+") or die("Failed opening ".KPA_PEOPLE);
    while($line=fgets($hndl_kpa_people)!==FALSE){
    echo "\nline: ".$line."\n";
}
?>
Context: 
The file looks like this in the file system:
-rw-r--r-- 1 snkdb snkdb   6096 dec 25 14:08 KPA_People.txt
(I'm the user snkdb)

The file's contents looks like:
et|2
Elisabet|3
okända|4...
```

The result looks like:

```
line: 1

line: 1

line: 1...
```

the expected result was:

```
et|2

Elisabet|3

okända|4...
```

as far as I understand the "while($line=fgets($hndl_kpa_people)!==FALSE)"
follows the convention in the manual and looks like it works in earlier scripts.
Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Add brackets so you have `while(($line=fgets($hndl_kpa_people))!==FALSE)`

Comment: `doSomething() or die()` is the worst thing that one can learn from the old PHP tutorials. Handle the errors properly, do not throw a blank page in the face of the visitor!

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```php
while($line=fgets($hndl_kpa_people)!==FALSE)
```

PHP is first evaluating the expression `fgets($hndl_kpa_people)!==FALSE` and then assigns it to the variable `$line`.

Furthermore, it is redundant to evaluate if something inside the `while` loop is different from `false`, since `while` loop runs while the condition it's evaluating is true.

So the line should be:

```php
while($line = fgets($hndl_kpa_people))
```

You can read more on Operator Precedence in the official documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

You can read more about `while` loop here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

---

**Edit:** Since there is a confusion in the comments whether reading an empty line will return `false` - it will not. Take the following simple example:

```php
<?php

$file = fopen('sample.txt', "r+");
$counter = 0;
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
    print_r("Counter: $counter - Line: " . $line);
    $counter++;
}
fclose($file);
```

with the following sample file:

```
test 123

test 234
test 345
```

The result from execution is:

```
Counter: 0 - Line: test 123
Counter: 1 - Line: 
Counter: 2 - Line: test 234
Counter: 3 - Line: test 345
```

Comment: Just a note, if `fgets` returns an empty line, that would also be considered false. So the comparison is valid!

Comment: @NigelRen Reading an empty line will not return `false`. I have updated my answer to demonstrate it.

Comment: I'm stunned. After 22 years of amateurish PHP programming I finally ask a question and it was answered within 5 seconds on Christmas day. Whew!

Comment: An empty line will normally contain an end of line chr, unless it is the last line.