# php while loop on reading file lines - do we need to compare fgets/fgetcsv to FALSE?

Tags: php, csv

In the official documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) we have the following example of reading CSV file line by line:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Both the `fgetcsv` and `fopen` return false if the operation could not be completed. I am curious if and why we really need to put `!== FALSE` comparisons in the code. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74913734/4314825) suggest they are obsolete.

Would removing comparisons to FALSE in fopen and fgetcsv have any negative consequences?

Comment: Well, have you tried it? But no, I don't see why you'd need that particularly.  What do you expect might go wrong?

Comment: Yes and it worked on my example file. I expect that there may be some nuance that does not come to my mind of php newbie. I love having full picture.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php - the manual gives an example. `if ($show_separators == TRUE)` is identical to `if ($show_separators)`

Comment: This is normally used when a function can return 0 or any other value that evaluates to 'false'.  So something like `fgets` which returns '' would need this.  As neither of these function return this sort of data (AFAIK) it's just not needed.

Comment: Just beware of "truth-y" comparisons though, where it takes advantage of PHP's loose typing - example: https://3v4l.org/tFbbZ . `$x` isn't boolean `true` there, but a value of another type where PHP deems it equivlent to `true` for the sake of comparisons. More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php . In your example though, it won't matter because (as per its documentation) fgetcsv will only return either `false` (obviously false-y) or an array containing a single field (which will be considered truth-y), so there's no danger of the wrong outcome.